# Count retweets per user by linking two tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
tweets               retweets
-----------------    ----------------
user_id  retweets    user_id (etc...)
-----------------    ----------------
1        0           1
2        0           1
                     1
                     2
                     2
```

I want to count the number of retweets per user and update tweets.retweets accordingly:

```
UPDATE users 
SET retweets = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM retweets WHERE retweets.user_id = users.user_id
)
```

I have been running this query two times, but it times out (on tables that are not that large). Is my query wring?

Also see the SQL Fiddle (although it apparently doesn't allow `UPDATE` statements): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f591e/1

Comment: not having environment to test. But can u add group by retweets.user_id in your select query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should be much faster than using subqueries for getting the count of tweets of each user (your correlated subquery will execute for ***each*** user):

```
UPDATE users a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) AS retweet_count
    FROM retweets
    GROUP BY user_id
) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
SET a.retweets = COALESCE(b.retweet_count, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your retweets table is not changing dynamically why not to gather data at first and then update destination table like this:

```
create table retweets_hist AS SELECT COUNT(*) AS retweets,user_id FROM retweets group by user_id;
```

then

```
UPDATE users 
SET retweets = NVL(
  SELECT retweets FROM retweets_hist WHERE retweets_hist.user_id = users.user_id
),0)
```

If it is dynamic, then I think using triggers is better.

The main issue here is **when there is a user which has never retweeted ever** counting it's retweets is time-consuming.

In answer to your question, Yes counting takes a fraction but counting something which never existed take time! this is the problem!

May this one would have better timing:

```
 UPDATE users 
    SET retweets = NVL(
                       SELECT retweets 
                         FROM retweets 
                        WHERE retweets.user_id = users.user_id),0)
  WHERE EXISTS(select * 
                 FROM retweets 
                WHERE retweets.user_id = users.user_id)
```

But then again you have to update **never retweets** to Zero.

**Keyword EXISTS is in Oracle I don't know if mysql supports it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The table is not dynamic. It is a database with historical data for research purposes. There are indeed many users who have never retweeted. I don't understand how this is time consuming because then counting only takes a fraction, no? And if not, how can I then ommit this consumption of time?